# Show image on input select file

Tags: html, css

I have done a input to change a profile image, but I would like that when I select a new file, my input changes automatically to the new picture.

```
<div class="form-group" align="center">
  <div style="position:relative; bottom:-90px; opacity:0.5; z-index:1; color:black;background:white;font-weight:bold">alterar</div>
  <label style="display: block" for="avatar">
    <img src="{{  $user->avatar }}" style="-moz-border-radius: 50px;border-radius: 50px;height: 80px" id="imgupload">
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="avatar" id="avatar" style="display: none">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure how I can accomplish that.

EDIT

I accomplished adding JS, but when I select a new image it's changing the rounded border..

JS:

```
    function readFile() {
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
          document.getElementById("imgupload").src = e.target.result;
        };
        FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
      }
    }

    document.getElementById("avatar").addEventListener("change", readFile, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gst96zax/

Comment: BTW center is deprecated use 'style="text-align:center"'

Comment: "{{  $user->avatar }}" Wha tit is? are you using angular JS or something else?

Comment: That's the url where the image is..

Comment: So you just want it so that when the input is changed, the img takes the input and updates it's src?

Comment: I know man I 'm asking where your getting that variable? Can you show us what you tried till now??

Comment: @ChrisW. That's it.

Comment: make input use database for background image and update database when user selects an image , i think that would help

Comment: But I don't want to upload as soon as the user selects the image.. Only when press save button...

Comment: then you can use php to turn image into base64 code and replace it in input css by jquery code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following JS

```
    function readFile() {
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
          document.getElementById("imgupload").src = e.target.result;
          document.getElementById("imgupload").style.width = "80px";

        };
        FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
      }
    }

    document.getElementById("avatar").addEventListener("change", readFile, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gst96zax/1